# Open subset of a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a topological space $T$, prove that a set $G\subset T$ is open if and only if every point $x$ $\in$ $G$ has a neighborhood contained in $G$

So far in the forward direction, I believe that for each element $x$ $\in$ G I need to find a set $G_1$ so that $x$ $\in$ $G_1$ $\subset$ $G$ where $G_1$ is open. However, I am unsure of how to construct these sets.

for the reverse direction, we know that each element $x_i$ $\in$ $G$ belongs to an open set $G_i$. Is it true that $\bigcup$ $G_i$ $=$ $G$?

Comment: For the forward direction, you don't know *any* sets that contain $x$...except for $G$.  For the reverse, the answer is *yes*; if you have any doubts you should probably include a quick proof.

Comment: How do you define a topological space? I ask the question as there are two different (and equivalent) definitions. And the answer to your question depends on the one you chose.

Comment: The forward direction is easy. Since $G$ is open and each $x\in G$  let $G_i=G$. The reverse direction is just as easy because each of the $G_i$s are subsets of $G$ so the union must be a subset of $G$ and since every point of $G$ is in one of the subsets, $G$ is a subset of the union.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: excellent point. In fact, there are lots of equivalent ways of defining a topological space (e.g., in terms of a closure operator).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have that a topological space is a pair $(X,$ $\tau$ $)$ consisting of a set $X$ and a topology $\tau$ on X. Where a Topology $\tau$ is a system of subsets $G$ $\subset$ $X$, called open sets (Relative to the topology), with the following two properties: 1) $X$ and $\emptyset$ belong to $\tau$ 2) arbitrary unions or finite intersections of open sets are open

Comment: While doing some other work I just learned that a base is a cover for a topological space. Now I believe that I can use this to prove the reverse direction as each open set must be a union of elements of the base? Would this be a suitable proof @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is open, we can take $G_x=G$ for any $x \in G$: then $G_x$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $x \in G_x \subseteq G$ is trivial (any set is a subset of itself).

On the other hand if for each $x \in G$ we have a neighbourhood $G_x$ of $x$ such that $x \in G_x \subseteq O$, then I claim

$$G=\bigcup \{G_x: x \in G\}$$

(**proof**:

$\subseteq$: if $p \in G$, then $p \in G_p \subseteq \bigcup \{G_x: x \in G\}$ and

$\supseteq$: if $p \in \bigcup \{G_x: x \in G\}$ there is some $x \in G$ with $p \in G_x \subseteq G$, so $p \in G$.

)

So $G$ is a union of open sets $G_x$ and so itself open by an axiom for topologies.

Comment: If each  $x\in G$ has a nbhd $N\subset G$, let $V$ be the set of all open subsets of  the set $G.$ Then $\bigcup V$ is an open subset of $G.$ And $\forall x\in G\,\exists U\in V\,(x\in U),$ so $G\subset \bigcup V.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, the AC-fearing way.

Comment: It does avoid AC but it's also very simple & short.